# Sum of all nodes in a binary tree giving incorrect output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to solve the following problem.
Problem statement: Given a binary tree, return the sum of the depth of all the nodes. For example, this is a binary tree.

```
          1
       /     \
      2       3
    /   \   /   \
   4     5 6     7
 /   \
8     9
```

The depth of the node with value 2 is 1.
Similarly, the Depth of node with value 4 is 2 etc...
The total depth of all nodes is 16.
I have written the following recursive solution which is giving me the incorrect output.
My pseudocode is as follows :

```
If the current node has no left and right child, then return;
Check if the current node has any left child. If it has, then:
   Add 1 to depthSoFar variable
   Add the depthSoFar value to totalDepth variable
   Then, recursively call the function with the left child as the current node
If the current node has the right child, then: 
      Add 1 to depthSoFar variable
      Add the depthSoFar value to totalDepth variable
      Then, recursively call the function with the right child as the current node
```

The code is as follows;

```
var nodeDepths = function(root) {
      var totalDepth = 0;
    function depth(root, depthSoFar) {
        if (root.left === null && root.right === null) {
            return;
        }
        // checking if it has left child
        if(root.left) {
            depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;
            // Add it to total
            totalDepth = totalDepth + depthSoFar;
            depth(root.left, depthSoFar);
        }
        if(root.right) {
            depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;
            totalDepth = totalDepth + depthSoFar;
            depth(root.right, depthSoFar);
        }
    }
    depth(root, 0);
    return totalDepth;
};
```

My output is 22 but the correct output is 16.

```js
var nodeDepths = function(root) {
      var totalDepth = 0;
    function depth(root, depthSoFar) {
        if (root.left === null && root.right === null) {
            return;
        }
        // checking if it has left child
        if(root.left) {
            depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;
            // Add it to total
            totalDepth = totalDepth + depthSoFar;
            depth(root.left, depthSoFar);
        }
        if(root.right) {
            depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;
            totalDepth = totalDepth + depthSoFar;
            depth(root.right, depthSoFar);
        }
    }
    depth(root, 0);
    return totalDepth;
};

class BinaryTree {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

var root = new BinaryTree(1);
root.left = new BinaryTree(2);
root.right = new BinaryTree(3);
root.left.left = new BinaryTree(4);
root.left.right = new BinaryTree(5);
root.right.left = new BinaryTree(6);
root.right.right = new BinaryTree(7);
root.left.left.left = new BinaryTree(8);
root.left.left.right = new BinaryTree(9);

console.log(nodeDepths(root))
```

I am not understanding where I am getting wrong. Any help in understanding the problem, would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: What happens to the `depthSoFar` variable if both `root.left` and `root.right` exist?

Comment: It would help people help you if you included a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem (mostly so we have the code that sets up the nodes). You can do one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @meriton - Yeah, literally *just* saw that. :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for sharing the tips. I have included the code snippet for convenience.

Comment: @meriton Sorry, I did not get it properly. Would you mind explaining, please? Thanks.

Comment: There are numerous ways to approach this but  one way is to keep track of each node for each depth and then take the sum of that number times their depth and keep a running sum of those values. Make sure to look up the difference between BFS and DFS for this approach. I think that it will be fairly obvious which one you'd need.

Comment: @AshequlHaque - meriton's point was that if you have both left and right, you do the `depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;` statement **twice**, once for the left and once for the right. That means you double-count the current node. If you fix that, your code returns the right result.

Comment: (I should have said you do **both** of the `depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;` statements, rather than that you do "the" statement "twice.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for helping me understand it.  I am not still not quite understanding it. I have removed the second **depthSoFar = depthSoFar + 1;** from the **if(root.right)** block. Doing so, making some of the test cases passing, but not all of them. I think I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for suggesting the other ways. I will try definitely. I am actually trying to make this code works. I have seen other nice solutions but this one I came by myself, so want to know how can I make this work. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @AshequlHaque - You remove it from *both* of those blocks, and do it once before them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is working perfectly now. Thank you very much :) I wish if I could understand/debug like you. Recursion sometimes feels very difficult for me to debug.

Comment: @AshequlHaque - I've been doing this for roughly 40 years. Give yourself time. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 3):

`sumDepths` has a simple inductive definition

1. if the input tree, `t`, is empty, return the empty sum, zero.
2. (inductive) the tree has at least one node. return the current depth, `d`, plus the sum of the recursive sub-problems, `sumDepths(t.left, d + 1)` plus `sumDepths(t.right, d + 1)`

```js
function sumDepths (t, d = 0) {
  if (t == null)
    return 0       // #1
  else
    return d + sumDepths(t.left, d + 1) + sumDepths(t.right, d + 1) // #2
}

function node (value, left, right) {
  return { value, left, right }
}

const tree =
  node
    ( 1
    , node
        ( 2
        , node(4, node(8), node(9))
        , node(5)
        )
    , node(3, node(6), node(7))
    )

console.log(sumDepths(tree)) // 16
```

Another way to think about the problem is write a depth `traverse` generator and sum each depth -

```js
function* traverse (t, d = 0) {
  if (t == null) return
  yield [d, t.value]
  yield *traverse(t.left, d + 1)
  yield *traverse(t.right, d + 1)
}

function node (value, left, right) {
  return { value, left, right }
}

const tree =
  node
    ( 1
    , node
        ( 2
        , node(4, node(8), node(9))
        , node(5)
        )
    , node(3, node(6), node(7))
    )

const sum =
  Array
    .from(traverse(tree), ([ depth, value ]) => depth)
    .reduce((r, d) => r + d, 0)

console.log(sum) // 16
```

Comment: Great answer. :-)